# Would an equation in the form ax + b = c/x be considered quadratic?

Tags: definition, quadratics

For example is $2x + 3 = \frac 5x$ quadratic?

On the one hand it has two solutions, $x = 1$ and $x = -5/2$ which is the number of solutions we'd expect from the fundamental theorem of algebra but on the other hand any equation in the form $ax + b = \frac cx$ would be undefined at $x = 0$ and every quadratic equation I'm familiar with is continuous over all real numbers. Is being continuous over all real numbers necessary for an equation to be called quadratic?

Comment: It's not quadratic since it's not "quadratic function = 0". It is equivalent to a quadratic equation together with the assumption $x \neq 0$.

Comment: It depends on how people are using the word in their particular context. Technically speaking there is no quadratic term anywhere; however, multiplying through by $x$ turns it into an indisputably quadratic equation (at the cost of changing the domain of definition slightly). In algebraic geometry one might talk about the degree of an equation in a way that makes the original equation quadratic.

Comment: It is a quadratic polynommial though as it is equal to $2x^2+3x=5$

Comment: I find it easier to talk about functions than to talk about equations, because many different equations can be equivalent to each other.

Comment: It'd be a lot more work to define precisely what a quadratic equation is than what a quadratic function is.  Are "$x^2 + 0\cdot e^x + 2 = 0$", "$x^2 +3 = 2x$", or "$x^{2^1} = 0$" quadratic equations? Well, I dunno, depends on your conventions.  On the other hand, all mathematicians would agree that the functions $f,g,h: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = x^2 + 0\cdot e^x + 2$, $g(x) = x^2 + 3$, $h(x) = x^{2^1}$ are all quadratic functions.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it has two solutions is not relevant here. The equation $2^x-x=0$ also has two solutions, but nobody would say that it is a quadratic equation. And the equation $x^2+1=0$ *is* a quadratic equation, in spite of the fact that it has no (real) solution.

A reasonable definition of quadratic equation would be: an equation of the type $q(x)=0$, where $q$ is a polynomial function with degree $2$. It would still be a quadratic equation even if we were only interested in solutions within a certain subset of $\Bbb R$ (such as, say, $(-\infty,1]$ or $\Bbb Q$).

Under this definition, your equation is *not* a quadratic equation. However, its solutions are the solutions of the quadratic equation $2x^2+3x-5=0$.

Answer (score 0):

This equation is not quadratic owing to its form. However, if the domain is restricted to non-zero numbers only, this could be thought of as a part of a quadratic curve, because it could be reduced to the quadratic form.

Answer (score 0):

Ys it is quadratic because
$$2x + 3 = \frac {5}{x}\
\iff 2x^2+3x=5 \\\implies 2z^2 +3x-5=0$$